# Comparison of rmongodb and Rmongo package

Tags: r, mongodb, web-applications

I have seen a lot of good questions/answers on how to use Mongodb from R using rmongodb. Recently I came across a github package called "Rmongo"...now I can also see it in CRAN. Can anybody tell me what is comparative differences in capabilities/focus of using these two packages ?

Comment: Personally I think this is a good question, though "pros & cons" might be better specified as "differences in capabilities/focus" or something to better conform to SO.

Comment: I have edited the question, could you please re-open it ?